# AWS CloudWatch Alarm not triggered for SQS Metrics "NumberOfMessagesReceived"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I am trying to trigger an alarm if message is sent to `SQS`. However, I see that the `CloudWatch` metrics indicates that there was a message but no alarm is triggered.

The alarm is currently in `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` state as well. For testing, I am sending a message via `boto3` client.

Below is my CloudFormation Template for `SQS` and `CloudWatch` alarm

```
QueueMessageAlarm:
Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
Condition: AlarmsEnabled
Properties:
  AlarmDescription: "Alarm if queue message is greater than 0"
  AlarmActions:
    - !Ref SampleNotificationTopic
  Namespace: "AWS/SQS"
  MetricName: "NumberOfMessagesReceived"
  Statistic: "Sum"
  Period: "900"
  EvaluationPeriods: "1"
  Threshold: "0"
  ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanThreshold"
  Dimensions:
    - Name: "QueueName"
    - Value:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - "KinesisStreamFileQueue"
          - "QueueName"

KinesisStreamFileQueue:
  Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
  Properties:
    QueueName: "StreamQueue"
```

Comment: also tried `"NumberOfMessagesReceived"` metrics but alarm is not being triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue by changing the `Dimensions` `properties` for the alarm resource. The resource needs to refer to the `arn` of the queue, and it was previously getting the `url` of it

```
Dimensions:
    - Name: QueueName
      Value: { "Fn::GetAtt": [ "KinesisStreamFileQueue", "QueueName"] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53490897/836214) metric instead of any "Received" metric.

The downside of using "Received" metrics is that unless you're constantly receiving messages, you're likely to get stuck in `INSUFFICIENT_DATA`, resulting in alarm issues.

Comment: thanks for looking into it. I figured out the issue by changing the the Dimensions of the Properties. I posted an answer